# Keystroke randomly duplicates on Linux Desktop

Tags: linux, kde

I have a problem that **keystroke randomly repeats in various KDE applications**.

Environment:

- Hardware: AMD CPU, Nvidia GPU, laptop
- OS: Arch Linux
- kernel: 5.4.55-1-lts (and change to latest: 5.7.12.arch1-1 has no effect)
- Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.19.4
- Display Manager: sddm 0.18.1-2

Examples:

- konsole 20.04.3

  - press `ENTER` occasionally makes `ENTER` and `ENTER`
  - on vim `p` command occasionally makes `pp`
- firefox 79.0, Chome 84.0.4147.105

  - `Ctrl+W` removes two tabs
- workspace change shortcut (set to ``` Meta+h``Meta+l ```) duplicates (move two workspace)

This problem:

- is **NOT a bounce key problem**. Because this problem occurs faster than bounce key delay speed.
- occurs about 2 times per 1 hour.
- is always doubled, not tripled.
- may not logged to `sudo dmesg` and `sudo journalctl -b` and `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Nothing suspicious, though I can find `kwin_x11: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated`.
- may NOT occurs on another tty (I haven't seen)
- possibly depends on each boot. Once this problem occurs, reboot is the best solution now.
- may NOT depends on load. But with more load, more likely to occur.

Then, I think this is a KDE related problem, But I don't know how to determine the problem occurs from and fix it.

Any ideas or clues?

---

**UPDATE 2020-08-27**

I found two information.

1. This is not a hardware probelm.
   In another keyboard, the issue remains.
2. I logged the key press/release time.
   This is what happened when key doubled.

```
pressed : 's'   2020-08-27 15:31:45.758807
pressed : 'p'   2020-08-27 15:31:45.829517
released: 's'   2020-08-27 15:31:45.865861 <-
pressed : 'p'   2020-08-27 15:31:46.213361 <- delay 450 ms
released: 'p'   2020-08-27 15:31:46.213597

pressed : 's'   2020-08-27 15:37:11.250339
pressed : 'p'   2020-08-27 15:37:11.290341 <-
pressed : 'p'   2020-08-27 15:37:11.659473 <- delay 440 ms
released: 's'   2020-08-27 15:37:11.659642
released: 'p'   2020-08-27 15:37:11.659741
```

My key repeat delay is 350 ms. and never hold key like this.
I'm thinking this is a kind of input delay problem in IME or KDE or OS...

---

**UPDATE 2020-09-19**

https://github.com/tildearrow/kwin-lowlatency

This may be a solution.
After installing this, the issue much less occurs. once in a week.